# Анализ полученных результатов теста TPC-H в запросе №16. Объёмы 30 Гб и 50 Гб

Tags: sql, sql-server, производительность, анализ-данных, нагрузочное-тестирование

Проводил тестирование TPC-H с объёмами баз в 30 Гб и 50 Гб на Microsoft SQL Server. В запросе №16 результаты по времени выполнения очень похожи. На 50 Гб кажется что время выполнения запроса на несколько сотых секунды даже меньше, чем время выполнения на 30 Гб. Чем это можно объяснить?

[image: Время выполнения запроса с разными объёмами данных]

Сам SQL запрос выглядит следующим образом:

```
select
    p_brand,
    p_type,
    p_size,
    count(distinct ps_suppkey) as supplier_cnt
from
    partsupp,
    part
where
    p_partkey = ps_partkey
    and p_brand <> 'Brand#34'
    and p_type not like 'MEDIUM BRUSHED%'
    and p_size in (10, 18, 2, 41, 20, 15, 5, 7)
    and ps_suppkey not in (
        select
            s_suppkey
        from
            supplier
        where
            s_comment like '%Customer%Complaints%'
    )
group by
    p_brand,
    p_type,
    p_size
order by
    supplier_cnt desc,
    p_brand,
    p_type,
    p_size;
GO
```

Актуальный (действительный) план запроса 30GB: [brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJljfPTrd)

Актуальный (действительный) план запроса 50GB: [brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1zMmP6B_)

Спецификация к тесту TPC-H: [disk.yandex.ru](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/wOtwSqQo3dLE-g) | [drive.google.com](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xBuIrtDE7m-aeSe_S6ocXvAMMNqichqK/view?usp=sharing)

Чем можно охарактеризовать это?

Comment: Тест выполнен по спецификации TPC-H: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/wOtwSqQo3dLE-g

Comment: Структура и планы находятся в ней

Comment: Чистая случайность. Так звёзды сошлись. Зависит от индексов и физического расположения данных на накопителе.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov. К сожалению не случайность. Тесты были выполнены по 10 раз на каждый объём. В посте - среднее значение. Даже, если я сейчас выполню тесты время выполнения будет практически одинаковым. При выполнении тестов к базе данных объёмом 10 Гб среднее время выполнения - 1,379 с.

Comment: Количество повторений теста, конечно, не влияет. Вы активно поработайте с базой: поудаляйте данные, повставляйте новые, поизменяйте их. Гигабайты данных. Но чтобы итоговый размер остался тот же. Потом снова прогоните тесты. С высокой долей вероятности время может измениться. Потому что физическое расположение данных изменилось. Какие-то страницы незаполнены полностью, их стало больше. Или, наоборот, страниц стало меньше, т. к. данные расположены на них более плотно.

Comment: У этого тестрования (TPC-H) есть своя утилита для генерации данных. Я попробую сгенерировать данные на 50 Гб заново и провести тестирование. Скорее всего сегодня вечером скажу результаты. Потом, если время не поменяется могу ещё на 30 Гб сгенерировать заново и прогнать, но думаю проблема не в данной БД, т.к. она по времени отличается от БД объёмом в 10 Гб примерно в 3 раза.

Comment: План запроса смотрели? Профилировщик использовали?

Comment: Я плохо в этом разбираюсь, поэтому и задал этот вопрос, так как мне необходимо понять хотя бы возможные причини из-за чего это могло произойти. Вот план запроса: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryfv05Krd

Comment: А план запроса по ссылке - это для какой из баз? Вы же знаете, что план зависит, в том числе, и от количества данных, и от самих данных?

Comment: @Yaant. Прошу прощения, добавил план для двух объёмов баз данных.

Comment: С виду планы не сильно то и отличаются. Второй план полностью параллельный, а в первом есть последовательное сканирование, но львиная доля работы по оценке происходит не там, где отличия. Только ведь это оценочные планы, давайте лучше актуальные (actual execution plan). Там и количество строк реальное можно сравнить с оценкой, и потоки будут видны, и выделение памяти, и статистика ожиданий.

Comment: @i-one. Спасибо за подсказку, изменил на актуальные планы выполнения запросов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот статистика времени для двух запросов (из планов):

[image: 30 Гб]

[image: 50 Гб]

Соотношение процессорного времени приблизительно 3:5, что соответствует объёму данных. Однако время выполнения почти одинаковое (на 50 Гб чуть быстрее).

> Чем это можно объяснить?

Это объясняется тем, что планы запросов разные (хотя и очень похожи). Главное отличие в том, что второй план полностью параллельный, тогда как в первом плане есть участок с последовательным сканированием:

[image: Последовательное сканирование]

Этот узел плана выполняет вот эту часть запроса:

```sql
select
    s_suppkey
from
    supplier
where
    s_comment like '%Customer%Complaints%'
```

Оптимизатор оценивает этот узел в 1% от всего плана, тогда как на самом деле на него тратится почти половина времени выполнения.

Эта же часть запроса во втором плане выполняется параллельно

[image: Параллельное сканирование]

двенадцатью потоками

[image: Потоки]

И хотя строк читается больше (500 тыс., тогда как для 30 Гб было 300 тыс.), время чтения значительно меньше (295 мс против 1844 мс).

Если бы для 30 Гб генерировался такой же план, как и для 50 Гб, то вероятнее всего (при отсутствии значительных ожиданий) время выполнения запроса для 30 Гб было бы меньше, чем время для 50 Гб.

Comment: Большое спасибо за понятное объяснение!